# Hover Text Make Div Change Colour - CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having trouble making a div change background colour when text is hovered.

I am using an absolute position for the div.book with an absolute value of text over it so the text hovers over the div, text on z-index 3 and div on 2.

When I hover the div the whole background changes, however the text is covering most the div and when its hovered nothing changes so I tried:

```css
h1:hover + div.book {
  background-color: rgba(333, 33, 33, 1);
}

.book {
  height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Book</h1> 
<div class="book"></div>
```

But I can't seem to get it to work?

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add your HTML please, without seeing the structure of your HTML how would we be able to accurately provide you with a solution?

Comment: `<h1>Book</h1>
           <div class="book">
          </div>`

"Book" is visually within the div class book from the absolute positions, I need when h1 is hovered div class="book" changes background colour. I have tried:

`h1:hover + div.book {
    background-color:rgba(333,33,33, 1);
}`

Comment: OK, ive added your html to your question. It seems to work fine?

Comment: Please read what andreas has added below your question.... Include all code to reproduce your problem! [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldnt work? Im using exactly that and having no joy and can't figure out why it won't work? Is it to do with absolute values? The Text is blocking me from hovering the div so thats why I want the div to change when the text is hovered is there another way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `h1` inside the `<div></div>`. The 2 elements will now overlap eachother. Add width to `.book`. And finally set the color (=textcolor) transparent so no letters will be displayed.

```css
h1:hover {
  background: red;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.book {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <h1>Book</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, only reason its outside is due to the font im using makes the gap at the top too big and doesnt sit centre. I have fixed though **by putting inside like you say and using a fixed position instead of absolute and moving it with margins to be centered**, thanks for helping though too many people who comment for commentings sake hoping for upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1:hover + div.book {
  background-color: rgba(333, 33, 33, 1);
}

.book{ position: absolute;    z-index: 2; background-color:rgba(333,33,33, 0.6);width: 230px; height: 60px; border-radius:40px 40px 40px 40px;-moz-border-radius:40px 40px 40px 40px;-webkit-border-radius:40px 40px 40px 40px; border:1px solid #999;}
div.book:hover{background-color:rgba(333,33,33, 1);}
h1 {font-family: 'tahoma', cursive; color:#FFF;font-size:48px; text-shadow:3px 3px #000; position:absolute; z-index:3;}
```

```html
<div class="welcome">    
           <center><h1>Book</h1></center>
           <div class="book">
           
          </div>
</div>
```